# What is the difference between ö and ö?

Tags: unicode

The following characters look alike. But they are not the same. I can not visually see their difference. Could anybody let me know what their difference is? Why are there two Unicode characters that are so similar?

```
$ xxd <<< ö
00000000: c3b6 0a                                  ...
$ xxd <<< ö
00000000: 6fcc 880a                                o...
```

Comment: one is Swedish and the other Icelandic :)

Comment: No time to write an answer, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence. These are *supposed* to be the same character, but due to history and accident there are two ways to represent it. Properly Unicode aware programs will treat them equally.

Comment: In this case you have the same glyphs (which should be handled equivalently, see e.g. normalization), but you may have visually the same glyphs, a.g. A may be Latin, or Greek, or Cyrillic (all with different codepoints)

Comment: @Adam So both characters are correct to use. In Swedish text, it is still OK to use the Icelandic version? If so, this seems to be weird.

Comment: @HTNW  "Properly Unicode aware programs will treat them equally." How to test their equivalence in python?

Comment: @user1424739 https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#comparing-strings

Comment: Two ways to produce diacritics, either pick a glyph that already has the diacritic (like U+02F6) or use the base glyph with a combining character (like U+006F and U+0308).  A decent library can resolve the ambiguity, like .NET's String.Normalize() or ICU's Normalizer class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is a single Unicode code point, while the second is two Unicode code points.  They are two forms of the same glyph (examples in Python):

```py
import unicodedata as ud

o1 = 'ö'  # '\xf6'
o2 = 'ö'  # 'o\u0308'

for c in o1:
    print(f'U+{ord(c):04X} {ud.name(c)}')
print()
for c in o2:
    print(f'U+{ord(c):04X} {ud.name(c)}')
```

```
U+00F6 LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS

U+006F LATIN SMALL LETTER O
U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS
```

Ensure the two strings are in the same normalization form (either composed or decomposed) for comparison:

```py
print(ud.normalize('NFC',o1) == ud.normalize('NFC',o2))
print(ud.normalize('NFD',o1) == ud.normalize('NFD',o2))
```

```
True
True
```